# How to render a bar chart with different series with only one entry per category in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I have  a chart with to series of data for a bunch of categories, every category only have values for one of the series:

[image]

The problem is that the bars don't start in the center of the category but on the begin or end, depending if its in first or the second series.

Is there a way to start the bar in center?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ms1kfrox/

Chart settings:

```
{
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Population (millions)',
      align: 'high'
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' millions'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        padding: 0,
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -40,
    y: 100,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Type1',
    data: [null, {
        y: 870
      },
      null, {
        y: 408
      },
      null
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Type2',
    data: [{
        y: 973
      },
      null, {
        y: 680
      },
      null, {
        y: 34
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `grouping:false` in plotOptions / bar object.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ms1kfrox/1/